# wkhtmltopdf prints "μ" incorrectly

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

`wkhtmltopdf` converts `μ` to `Î¼` when converting the HTML document to PDF. The HTML document renders `μ` perfectly.

`charset` meta tag is set to `utf-8` in the HTML document.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Sounds more like a bug to open on the repo not a question unless you also have a question?

Comment: Makes sense, I thought I was missing something. In that case should I just close this question and raise a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting encoding to `UTF-8` on server side fixed the issue `encoding: "UTF-8"`.